# How to avoid TABS at the end of last columns value in a hive text file?

Tags: hive

I have created a table as

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person_details(
dates date,
person_name string, 
person_age string
)
PARTITIONED BY (
country_name string, 
state_name String
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
LOCATION '/home/my_location';
```

After the script execution, inside the text file I can see spaces/ tabs at the end of person_age column's value.

for example:

```
2018-2-10|john|
2018-2-10|adam|26
2018-4-12|megan|34
2018-5-1|ron|
2018-6-20|robert|28
```

here, the last column has tabs (spaces) after the score values. 
Any suggestions please why this is happeneing?

Comment: Check the input file has any?

Comment: how are you loading the data?

Comment: @Prazy no; the input file doesn't have any space/ tabs.

Comment: @hlagos I am using some table's data as source data and finally join those to have the data

Comment: Can you add the following in script `STORED AS TEXTFILE`?